# Cleaner way of creating multiple objects from base class

Tags: java, static, instantiation

Let's say I have a class, called BaseClass, that looks something like this

```
class BaseClass{
    String var1;
    int var2;

    public void methodToBeOverridden(){}
}
```

and I need to create a significant number of classes that inherit this class. They will all override `methodToBeOverridden()`, but will all be instantiated in a static context. Since they all need to be static, they cannot be put in a single .class file to my understanding. Is there any cleaner way to do this than creating a separate .class file for each instance? I really doubt there is, but I thought I'd ask here before I got started on it just in case.

Comment: You can create [static nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) in the same class file. You can also declare more than one top-level class in a file if they're not public, but that's generally discouraged.

Comment: I don't think this BaseClass is necessary. I suggest use enum to implement it.

Comment: Maybe also a job for a functional interface and method handles. You can have all variants in a single class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach I take is to override implementations for an `enum` which implements an `interface`
 From https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Engine/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/engine/map/remote/MapFunction.java

```
public enum MapFunction implements SerializableBiFunction<MapView, Object, Object> {
    CONTAINS_VALUE {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(@NotNull MapView map, Object value) {
            Class vClass = map.valueType();
            return map.containsValue(convertTo(vClass, value));
        }
    },
    REMOVE {
        @Override
        public Object apply(@NotNull MapView map, Object o) {
            Class kClass = map.keyType();
            Class vClass = map.valueType();
            KeyValuePair kf = (KeyValuePair) o;
            return map.remove(convertTo(kClass, kf.key), convertTo(vClass, kf.value));
        }
    },
    REPLACE {
        @Override
        public Object apply(@NotNull MapView map, Object o) {
            Class kClass = map.keyType();
            Class vClass = map.valueType();
            if (o instanceof KeyValuePair) {
                KeyValuePair kf = (KeyValuePair) o;
                return map.replace(convertTo(kClass, kf.key), convertTo(vClass, kf.value));
            }
            KeyValuesTuple kf = (KeyValuesTuple) o;
            return map.replace(convertTo(kClass, kf.key), convertTo(vClass, kf.oldValue), convertTo(vClass, kf.value));
        }
    },
```

This allows me to have many implementations of the same method in a single `.java` file.  Note: this still creates multiple `.class` files.

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, I have no idea what a lot of that was. But you steered me in the direction of enums, which worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt that each of these classes has substantially different code inside `methodToBeOverridden`. They probably all differ by some piece of data - or maybe they fall into a few families like that - and you should make that piece of data be a constructor argument to the class and not have very few derived classes if any.

Comment: You seriously doubt based on what evidence? Or is this mere guesswork?

Comment: @EJP based on my experience in Java. Just sounds like a design smell and this is probably why. I'd be interested if the OP posts more but in the meantime I've *likely* left a pretty substantial hint that *hopefully* will get them to stop coding into a hole. I also may be wrong, which is fine.

Comment: You know what they say about making assumptions. ;)